# PHP 7 and PHPDocumentor install

Tags: php7

I've installed `PHP7`, `pear` and `phpdocumentor`.  Everything look good during the install but when I run `phpdoc` I receive the following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException: You have to enable opcache.load_comments=1 or zend_optimizerplus.load_comments=1. in /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php:193

PEAR Version: 1.10.1
PHP Version: 7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
Zend Engine Version: 3.0.0
Running on: Linux kevin-lt 3.13.0-46-generic #76-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 26
18:52:13 UTC 2015 x86_64

phpDocumentor: 2.8.5
```

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Bump! Anybody experience this before?

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the Pear package https://pear.phpdoc.org/, you will notice that the official package is based on version 2.8.5. This version doesn't support PHP7.0 syntax.

The project has released version 2.9.0 in May and if you want to install it, you'll need to get the version from Github. For example (go into the release tab so as to get the last one) :

```
wget https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/releases/download/v2.9.0/phpDocumentor.phar
```

Then, you need to follow the manual (Using the PHAR, except that you will replace the one from phpdoc.org by the one from Github)

1. Download the phar file from http://phpdoc.org/phpDocumentor.phar, or from a release listed on github
2. Move the file with sudo to your bin directory: `sudo mv phpDocumentor.phar /usr/local/bin/phpdoc`
3. Ensure the file has execute rights: `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phpdoc`
   Confirm it runs (you may have to restart your SSH session if you're connecting remotely first) by running `phpdoc --version` from any directory.

Comment: +1 for such a simple answer including restart SSH - that was the main problem not stated in similar answers